# Django Visual Studio The environment '....' is not available

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, virtual-environment

I had a virtual environment setup for Django 3 with visual studio. However at some point it seems that this previous environment has been damaged - and therefore is no longer working (nothing appears on git to have changed).

I therefore attempted to setup a new environment via the visual studio python environment options. I could setup a conda environment but it will not let me setup a python environment as "you will need to install a python interpreter...". However on the same page it states that the latest python 64 is installed.

It will not run with the conda environment that I have setup as it states "The environment '....' is not available."

I have tried creating a new solution with VS and this appears to work as intended. However it is not really an option to create a new solution as I will loose a lot of existing git commits along with this causing issues with existing servers.

Comment: may be you should try `CTRL + SHIFT + P` and type `Select interpreter` and VS code should activate the environment and it will create .vscode folder with settings. Even if it does not work may be try recreating your virtualenv with virtualenv [https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/]

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Found my own answer to this question.

As new projects were allowing virtual environments to be created I figured it must be something to do with visual studio storing some reference to an old interpreter.

Therefore, **Deleting the .vs folder** inside my project allowed regeneration of the visual studio files and creation of a new virtual environment.